# Django - How to get object on another app model without direct relationship in the parent model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a `Profile model`, `Award model` as child of the Profile model [which takes other award details like achievement detail], and a `List_of_awards model` as child of the Award model [which takes list of awards and a count of how may profiles has the specific award].

`Award model` is inline with the `Profile model` using `Foreignkey` and `List_of_awards model` as `Foreignkey field` in the `Award model` for the choices of awards.

What I am trying to do is, display the `List_of_awards` in the `Profile model`.
The idea originated when I was able to display the `List_of_awards` in the `list_display` of the `Award model', so, I was trying to link` List_of_awards`in the`Profile` which has no direct relationship.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
     first_name                          = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('First Name'), max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, )
     middle_name                         = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Middle Name'), max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
     last_name                           = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Last Name'), max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
     ....

class Award(models.Model):
    list_of_award       = models.ForeignKey('system_settings.Ribbon', related_name='awards_ad_ribbon', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name=_('Type of Award'), blank=True, null=True)
    achievement         = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('Achievement'))
    profile             = models.ForeignKey('reservist_profile.Profile', related_name='awards_ad_profile', verbose_name=_('Profile'), on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

     def image_tag(self):
        from django.utils.html import format_html
        return format_html('<img src="/static/media/%s" title="" width="75" /> %s' % (self.list_of_award.image,self.list_of_award.award))
     image_tag.short_description = 'Award'

class Ribbon(models.Model):
award      = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Award'), max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
award_desc = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('Description'), max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
image       = models.ImageField(verbose_name = _('Image'), upload_to = award_image_location, blank = True, null = True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = _('List of awards')
    verbose_name_plural = _('List of awards')

def __str__(self):
    return '%s' % (self.award)


def image_tag(self):
    return format_html('<img src="/static/media/%s" width="75" />' % (self.image))

image_tag.short_description = 'Award Image'
```

So, this is what I have in the moment, other function come up through research, but this particular scenario, I have no idea what the search key word is, so I apologize if it is already ask by someone. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('first_name',... 'list_of_awards')
    
    @admin.display(description='Awards')
    def list_of_awards(self, obj):
        return ",".join([k.list_of_award.award for k in obj.awards_ad_profile.all()]
```

More information can be found in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display).

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, even I have typo errors, you nailed it.

Comment: I slightly modify it to display the image using the `from django.utils.html import format_html_join`.